# exit application error

Tags: c#

I developed a simple windows application on .NET 4.
I'd like to pass a parameter to my application and if this parameter was empty the application should not continue running and quit.

I add an input parameter in the main method. It works fine when I debug it in my Visual Studio but when I execute my application directly Windows gave me this error:

"application has stopped working"

How can i handle it? I tested some codes but it doesn't work

```
 Application.ExitThread();
 Application.Exit();
```

This is may main method:

```
 [STAThread]
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     if(args.Count()==0)
      Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(); 

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new Form1());
 }
```

I looked at Windows  Event Viewer and found this error events

```
Application: WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
Stack:
at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
at System.Threading.Thread.Abort()
at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main()
```

and another:

```
Faulting application name: WindowsFormsApplication1.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time 
stamp:    0x50e775e3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7c78c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000a49d
Faulting process id: 0x15b4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdeade1bdab018
Faulting application path: C:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1 
 \bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 5a6d1a1f-56d1-11e2-8ffd-20cf30e7bd24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get the reason for your code above.

> if this parameter was empty application do not continue running and
>   exit works.

You could easily code in this way

```
 [STAThread]
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     if(args.Length > 0)
     {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new Form1());
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would expect this with the code you have supplied. Calling `Thread.Abort()` raises an exception on the thread (`ThreadAbortException`, which will be uncaught).

If all you want to do is stop processing with no arguments, simply return:

```
[STAThread]
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     if(args.Length ==0) return; // Will leave and end the application

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new Form1());
 }
```

You also are using `Count()` on the array when `Length` will simply do. Minor detail though.